# Blogger options missing

Tags: blogger

I see some of the options missing in the new post wizard of Blogger, as in the image below.

[image]

There I don't see text alignment to center/left/right and *Numbered List* or *Bulleted List* etcetera. My friend told me he can view them all. How can I get those options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the screenshot shows, you're currently in HTML editor view, which has only the options that you see. Click on **Compose** on top left of the editor to see other options.

[image]